# Plusquamperfekt oder nicht?

Tags: perfect-tense

Ich habe etwas auf einer Seite gelesen und seitdem frage ich mich, ob das richtig ist oder nicht. Der Teil dieses Textes ist so:

> Duda **hatte** nach Protesten in vielen polnischen Städten ein Veto gegen zwei von drei geplanten Gesetzen **eingelegt**.

Ist diese Verbform Plusquamperfekt und falls ja warum? Sollte man hier lieber Perfekt benutzt haben oder was?

Comment: Ohne Kontext ist die Frage, ob Plusquamperfekt hier korrekt ist, nicht zu beantworten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Ist diese Verbform Plusquamperfekt?**
   Ja
2. **Falls ja: warum?**
   Zum einen liegt das Vollverb (»eingelegt«, eine Form von »einlegen«) als Partizip Perfekt vor, zum anderen erscheint das Hilfsverb (»hatte«, eine Form von »haben«) im Präteritum. Beides zusammen definiert ein Plusquamperfekt.
3. **Sollte man hier lieber Perfekt benutzt haben oder was?**
   Das Plusquamperfekt wird verwendet, um einen Vorgang zu schildern, der zeitlich **vor** einem bestimmten Referenzpunkt geschieht, der selbst bereits in der Vergangenheit liegt.
   Beispiel:

   > Wir berichteten bereits gestern von den Vorgängen im polnischen Parlament. **Zu diesem Zeitpunkt hatte Duda sein Veto bereits eingelegt.**

   - Referenzpunkt: Unser gestriges Berichten von den Vorgängen im polnischen Parlament.
   - Darauf bezogenes, und davor liegendes Ereignis: Dudas Veto.

   Wenn es keinen solchen Referenzpunkt gibt, ist das Plusquamperfekt unzulässig.
   Beispiel:

   > *Ein Reporter meldet sich von einer Pressekonferenz, im Hintergrund sieht man Duda noch am Rednerpult stehen. Der Reporter sagt:*
   >   **»Duda hatte soeben ein Veto eingelegt.«**

   In diesem Beispiel ist das Plusquamperfekt fehl am Platz, weil es keinen Referenzpunkt in der Vergangenheit gibt, vor dem das Ereignis (Veto) geschieht.

   Das Problem mit dem Plusquamperfekt ist, dass nicht immer klar erkennbar ist, ob ein solcher Referenzpunkt existiert. Die *»Proteste in vielen polnischen Städten«* sind jedenfalls kein solcher Referenzpunkt, denn das Veto fand ja nicht *vor* den Protesten statt, sondern erst danach.

   Du lieferst in deiner Frage leider zu wenig Kontext. Vielleicht wird in einem anderen Satz ein Ereignis geschildert, dass als solcher Bezugspunkt fungieren könnte, dann wäre das Plusquamperfekt in Ordnung. Wenn ein solcher Bezugspunkt aber fehlt, muss eine andere Zeitform gewählt werden.

---

### Nachtrag

Ich habe die [Quelle](http://www.dw.com/de/25072017-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-39822849) gefunden. Die Meldung lautet:

> Trotz des Vetos von Staatspräsident Duda will die polnische Regierung am geplanten Umbau des Justizsystems festhalten. Wir werden nicht zurückrudern", sagte Ministerpräsidentin Beata Szydlo. Das Veto von Staatspräsident Andrzej Duda habe die Arbeiten an der Reform lediglich verlangsamt. **Duda hatte nach Protesten in vielen polnischen Städten ein Veto gegen zwei von drei geplanten Gesetzen eingelegt.** Er wolle damit den inneren Frieden wahren, sagte der Staatspräsident zur Begründung. ...

Der Satz *»Das Veto von Staatspräsident Andrzej Duda habe die Arbeiten an der Reform lediglich verlangsamt.«* ist die indirekte Wiedergabe einer Aussage von Ministerpräsidentin Beata Szydlo. Das Tätigen dieser Aussage ist ein Ereignis in der Vergangenheit.

Der darauf folgende Satz *»Duda hatte nach Protesten in vielen polnischen Städten ein Veto gegen zwei von drei geplanten Gesetzen eingelegt.«* ist eine Erklärung des Autors der Meldung. Der Autor erklärt darin dem Leser, was es mit diesem Veto auf sich hat. Darin schildert er ein Ereignis (nämlich das Einlegen des Vetos), das zeitlich vor einem Referenzereignis (nämlich Frau Szydlos Aussage) stattgefunden hat. Der inhaltliche Bezug entsteht dadurch, dass der Autor der Meldung das frühere Ereignis (Veto) als Begründung für das spätere (Szydlos Aussage) anführt.

Es sind also alle Bedingungen erfüllt, die man für ein Plusquamperfekt braucht, und somit ist seine Verwendung völlig korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Unter der Annahme, dass es sich beim Kontext um eine Meldung im Präteritum handelt, ja. Denn bezogen auf den Zeitpunkt des gemeldeten Vorgangs war das Veto noch weiter in der Vergangenheit und bereits abgeschlossen.